# get Date for the last of a number of weeks

Tags: java, date

I use this code in order to get the date for the last a nberofWeeks but i always got a null value.

```
  public static String getDateOfLastWeeks(int nberofWeeks){
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,-nberofWeeks);
            return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        }
```

Is it the right way?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: None of these variables or return values can be `null`.

Comment: yes, this code works, the problem is not here. paste the calling code

Comment: yes, is related for the calling code where i miss the format of the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not giving null value. Your are doing the thing in a right way.